# flutter Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInvalidArgumentException reason: ‘-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

while using youtube_player_flutter plugin in ios the media player is crashing  below given the error massage

Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInvalidArgumentException’, reason: ‘-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eacf5c00’
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 2):

Simply upgrade the youtube_player_flutter version to `8.0.0`
I was facing this issue and updating the version resolved it. Thanks